# how to run functions one after the other while using redis?

Tags: node.js, redis, promise

I have the following code

```js
var arr1 =['1','2','3'];
client.sadd("arr1",arr1);
var arr2=['2','4','6'];
var arr3 =['3','6','9'];
client.sadd("arr2",arr2);
client.sadd("arr3",arr3);
client.sadd("arraylist",'arr1','arr2','arr3');
function getValue(value){
 client.smembers("arraylist",function(err,data){
  if(err) console.log(err);
  else {
   console.log(data);
  data.forEach(function(res){
   console.log(res);
   client.smembers(res,function(err,data){
    if(err) console.log(err);
    else data.forEach(function(val){
     if(val==value){
      client.sadd("validarr",res);
         console.log("stored!")
     }
    })
   })
   
  
  })
  
  }
 })
}
  function randarr(){
 client.srandmember("validarr",function(err,response){
  if(err) console.log(err);
  else console.log(response);
 })
};


promise.resolve(getValue(2)).then(function()
{
 console.log("hey");
 promise.resolve(randarr()).then(function(){
  console.log("done")
 },function(err){console.log("error")})
})
```

I want to execute the function randarr() after the complete execution of the function getValue , because i want to use the saved set validarr in the next function randarr().

i tried using async.series. It turns out that both the functions were running simultaneously and printing the output in order.

So by using promise.then i am facing the same error
The output for the code using promises :

```
hey 
done
connected
[ 'arr2','arr3',arr1']
arr2
arr3
arr1
null
stored!
stored!
```

The functions are not getting executed in order.What should i use inorder to run the functions one after another.

Can someone help me with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement transaction commands into Redis, by using the [MULTI/EXEC commands](https://redis.io/commands/multi).